# Is this code safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection

I have a column in a MySQL table that can be either 0 or 1. If the user doesn't enter 0 or 1 then I just set the value to 0.
I was wondering if this PHP code would be "safe" from SQL injection:

```
$flag = $_GET["f"];
if ($flag != 1) $flag = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * from table WHERE column=$flag";
$db->query($sql);
```

I usually use prepared statements, but I was wondering if this code is full-proof.
If this can be broken, then I would like to see an example.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't simply use prepared statements, everywhere and always, so you don't have to wonder.

Comment: @MattBall not everybody likes prepared statements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about redundant security analyses and refutation inquiries.

Comment: @bwoebi: It's not really a matter of "like" or "dislike". That's the way you do it. Coming up with some escaping function isn't a good solution.

Comment: @Blender why not? it works well with an escape function?

Comment: writing queries generally works well with escape functions… you don't need any prepare (the only I do is aliasing `real_escape_string` by `esc` because the name is so long…) . Or why should I really use prepared statements?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't safe. Example SQL injection: `1 OR 1 = 1`

This is equal to 1, because `(int)"1string" === 1`.

I'd consider to explicitely `(int)` cast before passing it to the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table WHERE column=".(int)$flag;
```

Comment: True. See type juggling in php for further info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: He could also just change his comparison to `if ($flag !== 1)`

Comment: @Mike no, he couldn't, because `$_GET["f"]` (and so `$flag`) are strings.

Comment: You're right. `if ($flag !== "1")` then :P